# Warning: TwinCAT HMI Server: [WW ADS] Unable to connect to the local TwinCAT System: ERR_PORTDISABLED (0x00000012

Tags: twincat

Warning: TwinCAT HMI Server: [WW ADS] Unable to connect to the local TwinCAT System: ERR_PORTDISABLED (0x00000012
What does it mean?
Thank you very much.

The message was the result of the project creation action in Twincat 3.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue just now. I could not add any mappings either because of this issue. My project used to target a remote PLC instance, but i've changed it to a local target as i'm not able to reach the site at the moment. My solution was to not only change the target to a local environment but also change my runtime AmsNetId, as it was still set to the route of the remote machine. That did it for me. You'll find this setting TwinCAT HMI Server Configuration --> ADS --> Runtimes --> the runtime of the datasource. Make sure it's pointing towards the source you're running the PLC instance at.